# grunt-usemin: Retaining async attribute

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

Even when all the scripts inside the build comment have the async attribute, grunt-usemin ignores it. Going to the index.html manually everytime I build doesn't feels quite right.

Any solution?

Comment: Github issue here https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/79